# How to override customer address template

Tags: customer, shipping-address, customer-address, address

how to override customer address from customer account area and shipping option at checkout.
I aim to add a regex to stop customers from entering special characters and letters.

Customer account address book / More addresses we add.
Checkout area addresses again more addresses we add.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you it's the source of info :

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/override-address-book-phtml-in-magento-2/